# Make Gmail show name of unread email sender, rather than of original poster

Tags: gmail

Situation:

1. Alice sent an email 3 months ago, and quit the company.
2. Every day Bob and Chiara exchange a few email in that thread.

Problem:

- Expectation: When Bob sends a new email in that thread, I would expect Gmail to show me Bob's name at the left of the title.
- Reality: The name at the left of the title is always "Alice".

So when I check my unread emails, it always looks like Alice is back.

Question: Is there any way to make Gmail show the name of the sender of one the yet-unread messages, rather than the name of the original poster?

I am hoping for a setting, but I am OK with a browser extension too.